# Image - onclick event in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am using this library - datetimepicker_css.js in my html/jquery code. Whenever I click on the image, a time format like mm:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss populates in input tag.

```
 Start time:<input type="text" id="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25" name="stime" />                                                                                                                        
 <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true)" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

I am trying to implement same in react js code, and facing issues doing so. I could populate start_time but couldn't do a onclick of image tag and replace in the start_time field. Any help/suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

```
  render() {
        return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input value={this.state.first_name} onChange={this.setFirstName} placeholder="First name"/>
                    <input value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.setLastName} placeholder="Last name"/>
                    <input value={this.state.start_time} onChange={this.setStartTime} placeholder="Start Time" id="demo1" name="stime"/>
                    <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true)"/>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>

        )
    }

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Doe",
            start_time: "03/11/2016",
        };
    },         
   setStartTime(event) {
        this.setState({start_time: event.target.value});
    },
```

Comment: what is your html for image?

Comment: @KishoreBarik edited the code

Comment: change `onclick` to `onClick` in image tag

Comment: @KishoreBarik Got this error : I am not sure how to use Image event as function.
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string

Comment: ok now your onClick event is getting triggered. Now the error you are getting because the function you provided as string where it should be a function. you can bind a function of the component which will call `NewCssCal ('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true)`

Comment: @KishoreBarik Do you have an example of how is it done? I am pretty new to react and get confused on the working pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
render() {
        return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input value={this.state.first_name} onChange={this.setFirstName} placeholder="First name"/>
                    <input value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.setLastName} placeholder="Last name"/>
                    <input value={this.state.start_time} onChange={this.setStartTime} placeholder="Start Time" id="demo1" name="stime"/>
                    <img src="images2/cal.gif" onClick={this.populateDate}/>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>

        )
    },
populateDate(){
   NewCssCal('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true);

},

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Doe",
            start_time: "03/11/2016",
        };
    },         
   setStartTime(event) {
        this.setState({start_time: event.target.value});
    },
```

Note: make sure your **NewCssCal** function is globally available

Comment: This works. But when i try to setState the input tag, I face an error .

              <input value={this.state.start_time} onChange={this.setStartTime} placeholder="Start Time" id="demo1" name="stime"/>
                 <img src="images2/cal.gif" onClick={this.populateDate}/>

 setStartTime(event) {
            this.setState({start_time: event.target.value});
        },
 populateDate(event){
            NewCssCal('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true);
            this.setState({start_time: event.target.value});

        },

Comment: Error in the sense, I am changing the state of input tag value after the image click event. This needs to be updated as the target.value of input field but its not! Its still showing the previous value ( default ) of the input field. Does this not work?

 populateDate(event){
            NewCssCal('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true);
            setStartTime(event);

        },

Comment: have a look on https://jsfiddle.net/KishoreBarik/xrnbb63m/1/
it's working there. if it's still not working for you remove `value={this.state.start_time}` from **demo1** input and check

Comment: This is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/adwantgoutam/cfthcqLk/2/

I tried it all, but no luck.

Comment: your fiddle is not even running. Have you forked reacjs properly? I can't test there

Comment: I have extended and provided the detailed code in the below question. I am still quite not sure how to update the input text field value after the onclick of the image.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950311/react-js-unable-to-update-text-after-img-onclick-event