# React JS - unable to update text after IMG onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to update the input text field ( Start time ) after the onClick={this.populateDate}. But I get the default value passed to the AJAX call to PHP.

https://jsfiddle.net/adwantgoutam/rg68Lyfk/

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo "Hello World";
$stime= $_GET['first_name'];
$etime= $_GET['last_name'];
$xyz= $_GET['start_time'];
echo "\n";
echo $stime;
echo "\n";
echo $etime;
echo "\n";
echo $xyz;
?>
```

Output : 
Hello world!
John
Doe
03/11/2016 ( not the updated one after we click date through image onclick ).

```
   var Hello = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input value={this.state.first_name} onChange={this.setFirstName} placeholder="First name"/><br/>
                <input value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.setLastName} placeholder="Last name"/><br/>
                <input value={this.state.start_time} onChange={this.setStartTime} placeholder="Start Time" id="demo1" name="stime"/>
                <img src="https://rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/sample/images2/cal.gif" onClick={this.populateDate}/><br/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

    )
},
     handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = this.state;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://localhost:8082/PFT/login.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                //$('#resultip').html(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert("Data sending failed");
            }
        });
    },
  populateDate(){
    NewCssCal('demo1','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24',true);

  },

getInitialState() {
    return {
        first_name: "John",
        last_name: "Doe",
        start_time: "03/11/2016",
    };
},         
   setStartTime(event) {
      console.log( event.target.value)
        this.setState({start_time: event.target.value});
     }
  });

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Hello />,
     document.getElementById('container')
 );
```

I have attached my code in jsfiddle and above is the PHP script. I am not sure where exactly or how to process this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code with all the actions/functions as well?

Comment: @Kujira All the code is in https://jsfiddle.net/adwantgoutam/rg68Lyfk/

Comment: I do not see any of the `set_` functions and the `handleSubmit`?

Comment: @Kujira Not sure i fjsfiddle is updated. I have edited the code above.

Comment: How do all the `set_` functions look like? The state might not be updated properly.

Comment: @Kujira I have the set fuction for my input shown above. I am not sure where the miss would be. I assume if the input text is changed ( after clicking img onclick ). It should have triggered setStartTime(event)  and updated the start_time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the date picker library you are using. To make this code work you'll have to add componentDidMount as follows.

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.getElementById('demo1').onchange= this.setStartTime;
}
```

Then you need to modify you **setStartTime** function as follows

```
setStartTime() {
        this.setState({start_time: document.getElementById('demo1').value});
}
```

Because the library is triggering change event programatically(as the value is being changed programmatically). Hence you'll not get the event object.

Though doing so will make your code work, my suggestion will be to use any react library for date-time picker(if you don't have the dependency to use this only) which provide proper configuration as per your requirement. Also try to use **refs** instead of document.getElement.... which is the react way of interacting with dom.